# How do I find or derive circumspherical radii, surface area, and volume for these 5 non-traditional concave polyhedra?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d, computational-geometry, polyhedra

How do I find or derive circumspherical radii, surface area, and volume for these 5 non-traditional concave polyhedra?

As much of a mathematics enthusiast I am, I'm stuck on a huge roadblock in further developing my code for the paper that shows the value in different geometries at the nanoscale for nanomedicine: There are five shapes that I am having trouble deriving the circumspherical radii, and thus, the equations of surface area and volume, to solve my equations:

- Medial Rhombic Triacontahedron
- Dodecadodecahedron Medial Triambic
- Icosahedron Ditrigonal
- Dodecadodecahedron Excavated
- Dodecahedron

I've scoured the internet to find some approximations but the only one I could find was based off of one of those solids so far and it's not a modifiable equation as I cannot denote where the side length comes into play (they are just constants based off of a unit edge length): http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/MedialRhombicTriacontahedron.html

I was wondering if anyone knew how to derivate the shape's equations or where I can find the correct resource? I'd derivate it myself but it's a bit above my scope of knowledge. I need a physical solid to cut and manipulate to try to find basic ratios at the very least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the polyhedra are such that any line through "the center" of the polyhedron intersects the surface exactly twice, each face is a simple planar polygon, and you have the 3D coordinates for each face polygon, you can calculate the surface area as the sum area of the face polygons, and the volume as the sum of the volumes of the pyramids with their faces at their bases.

That center does not have to be any specific center (like center of mass, or centroid); it suffices that such a point exists, and it is at origin (wrt. the vertex coordinates), for the following treatment.

Let's assume the polyhedron is centered at origin. For each planar face described by its polygon vertices $\vec{v}_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i)$ counterclockwise or clockwise around its face unit normal vector $\hat{n}$, $i = 1 \dots n$, and point $\vec{o}$ on the face plane, inside the face polygon,
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{n} &= \left( \vec{v}_{i-1} - \vec{o} \right) \times \left( \vec{v}_i - \vec{o} \right) \\
\hat{n} &= \frac{\vec{n}}{\left\lVert\vec{n}\right\rVert} \\
\end{aligned}$$
where $\vec{v}_0 = \vec{v}_n$.  (Although $\lVert\vec{n}\rVert$ may vary for $i = 1 \dots n$, $\hat{n}$ will always be the same, regardless of which pair of vertices (non-collinear with $\vec{o}$) are chosen; otherwise, the face is not planar.)

The surface area of this face is then calculable via the Shoelace formula, e.g.
$$A = \frac{1}{2} \left\lVert \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\vec{v}_{i-1} - \vec{o}) \times (\vec{v}_i - \vec{o}) \right\rVert$$
and the volume of the pyramid corresponding to this face is
$$V = \frac{A}{3}\left\lvert \vec{o} \cdot \hat{n} \right\rvert$$
The dot product is positive if the normal points outwards, negative if the normal points inwards; its magnitude is the height of the pyramid, measured perpendicular to the base.

Due to symmetries, you can typically calculate the total volume and surface area in exact terms (given exact vertex coordinates), since these polyhedra have many symmetries (similar faces); I suggest using a Computer Algebra System like Maple, Maxima (wxMaxima), or Sagemath.

As far as I know, the mentioned polyhedra are sufficiently symmetric that the circumradius is equal to the maximum distance between a vertex and the center of the polyhedron; with each one of these having at least four vertices at such distances.  For dodecahedron and all other platonic solids, all vertices are at the same distance from the center, as all their vertices pass through the circumsphere.

---

In purely geometric terms, the above attempts to explain how to compute the surface area of these polyhedra by computing the area of each unique face – these being highly symmetric, there are rarely more than two or three different faces – and the volume as the sum of volumes of the pyramids corresponding to those faces, with the pyramid apex at the center of symmetry.  Compare to fruits and berries that are composed of clusters of individual wedges.

Let's consider [medial rhombic triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_rhombic_triacontahedron) (Wikipedia), DU<sub>36</sub>  (dual uniform polyhedron 36), as an example.  (I recommend you find the exact [index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_uniform_polyhedra) of the polyhedra, since I could not determine for sure exactly which polyhedra three of the five listed refer to.)

It consists of 12 "spikes", each with five equal faces, so essentially has 60 identical face polygons.  Each face polygon is a quadrilateral, with two short and two long sides, each pair consecutive (and can be decomposed to two unequal triangles).

If we call the surface area of each face polygon $A_f$, the surface area of the entire medial rhombic triacontahedron is $A = 60 A_f$.

If we call the distance from each face plane from the center of the polyhedron $h$ – due to the symmetries this is the same for all of them –, the volume of the entire medial rhombic triacontahedron is $V = 60 \cdot \frac{A_f}{3} h = 20 A_f h$.

Note how the height $h$ of the face pyramid is measured in the perpendicular direction from the face.  This height is the same as the distance from the face plane – the plane extending the face to infinity – to the center of symmetry of the entire polyhedron.

The circumspherical radius $R$ is the same as the distances from the tips of the "spikes" to the center of symmetry of the polyhedron.

Comment: I'm extremely confused. How do I find the planar form of these within the bounds I want them to be in? I know the general coordinated based on a unit-length but that's it and I could find the plane but how do I bound the plane and how do I represent that as a vector? I assume the arrows are vector notation? I'm sorry, I'm really poor at advanced mathematics like this, you'll have to explain it in simpler terms. And I just don't understand how I can return an area and volume for this without it being a vector. I'm extremely confused and I'm sorry if my incompetence is infuriating.

Comment: @WesleyAllenWilliams: I see – and don't worry; "incompentence" with your attitude is really just unrealized learning potential, which is a positive thing :).  Basic vector algebra (notation, dot product, cross product at minimum) would be extremely useful here.  The method I describe above requires one to know the coordinates of each face polygon; those are rarely listed for these polyhedra in the literature.  I was hoping you had 3D models of these objects, from which those coordinates could be extracted.  Let me try a completely different track, as an addition to my "answer".

Comment: I can try to find a 3D model of it but I'm not sure the coordinate points are listed on it.

Comment: I was able to do the derivations for the rest. Since you mentioned extending the face, I did so as an infinite plane until the perpendicular line hits the center. My hypotenuse was the circumspherical radii and derived  "h" from that and use a protractor to find the angle need from the face to the midline of the polyhedron. Now, the surface area and volume is in terms of circumspherical radii from h in terms of it as well! I'll do the rest for the four other if I can... Thanks so much! @Glärbo

Comment: I also wanted to ask about your "berries and wedges" analogy...:are the pyramids flipped to approximate the area exactly or is it a general approximation since it isn't a regular Platonic convex polyhedra? @Glärbo

Comment: @WesleyAllenWilliams: Yes, that's exactly how you get $h$ and $R$.  The pyramids are not an approximation, but a decomposition of the polyhedron: the pyramids are exact.  It is general in the sense that if you have a point inside the polyhedron and any line through that point intersects the polyhedron surface exactly twice, this method will give exact correct answers for that polyhedron.  For regular polyhedra, the center of symmetry gives many exactly same pyramids, so less math work is needed.  It is good to hear this helped you make progress!

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the “known” polyhedra. For example, you know that medial rhombic triacontahedron (MRT) is a stellation of a rhombic triacontahedron (RT).
There are 3 types of vertices in MRT. By the symmetry, you can see that the outer vertice $A$ is a scaled vertice of a RT by some coefficient $\alpha$. Medial vertice $B$ is a scaled face center by $\beta$ and the inner vertice is actually a vertice of RT.

By claiming that $A$ and $B$ belong to the plane of the red face, you can find $\alpha=(\sqrt5+1)/2$ (golden ratio) and $\beta=\sqrt5-1$.

[image]

After you have found the coordinates of all vertices, it's not hard to find the metrics you are interested in.

As for other polygons, you can do similar things:

- Dodecadodecahedron Medial Triambic — not sure what it is
- Ditrigonal icosahedron is as far as I understand is the same as excavated dodecahedron — you start with dodecahedron and downscale face centers until they form regular triangle
- Dodecadodecahedron Excavated — not sure what it is
- Dodecahedron — if it's a regular one, I don't really understand what is the problem with finding anything about [one of the platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron)

Comment: Sorry, here's the list that isn't messed up: Medial Rhombic Triacontahedron
Dodecadodecahedron
Medial Triambic Icosahedron
Ditrigonal Dodecadodecahedron
Excavated Dodecahedron

Comment: I'm going to try the derivations you gave me and see if I can apply them. Luckily, all five shapes have their own faces you presented for the first shape (the kite). If you are confused, I found the shapes on wikipedia for you to see. Just type them in that site. @Vasily Mitch

Comment: I'm a bit lost. How would coordinate points translate to an equation? Sorry, I'm not great at advanced mathematics like this.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the red and blue kite is referring to. Is this a projection of it's dual inscribed or is the MRT inscribed into it? I have so many questions and I'm super confused...I don't even see how I would derivate the equations from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_triacontahedron @Vasily Mitch

Comment: Hey there, I pltted the coordinates of RT, its dual, but what does scaling these coordinates do for me when I don't know how to bound the planes or solve for the volume? Sorry for all of the questions, I'm so lost and I am running out of time @Vasily Mitch

Comment: Red rhombus is the face of RT, pink rhombus is the stellation of the same face, blue kite is the face of MRT

Comment: You can bound a point $P$ to a plane $ABC$ by setting a determinant of a matrix $(P-A, B-A, C-A)$ to zero. You can find the volume by summing over the pyramids as Glärbo already suggested.

Comment: Then what is the pink? Is that no area on the MRT? and what is point P? My coordinate points from RT? I don't understand what Glarbo is saying at all.